# Package requirement 'psycopg2==2.9.1' not satisfied pycharm macos

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm, psycopg2

after long hours of trying: i installed psycopg2==2.9.1 with pip
[installed with pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTjni.png)

I tried adding it to all the interpreter paths i could find but still keep getting this message:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19lE1.png)

I tried as well restarting pycharm, invalidate caches ..

When trying to just install it with pycharm i get this error messege:

```
    Collecting psycopg2==2.9.1
  Using cached psycopg2-2.9.1.tar.gz (379 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'error'

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: '/Users/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/data_index-development/venv/bin/python' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fj/blrljwxs22q3csr4fqw7ycmc0000gn/T/pip-install-myo1zngt/psycopg2_e9a9698f63464cb99bc5bf3655675aa2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fj/blrljwxs22q3csr4fqw7ycmc0000gn/T/pip-install-myo1zngt/psycopg2_e9a9698f63464cb99bc5bf3655675aa2/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/fj/blrljwxs22q3csr4fqw7ycmc0000gn/T/pip-wheel-lbvr1lzp
       cwd: /private/var/folders/fj/blrljwxs22q3csr4fqw7ycmc0000gn/T/pip-install-myo1zngt/psycopg2_e9a9698f63464cb99bc5bf3655675aa2/
  Complete output (53 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
  copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
  copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
  copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
  copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
  copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
  copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
  copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
  copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
  copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
  copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
  copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
  
  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg
  /usr/bin/clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/MISSING/DEPS//stage/include -I/MISSING/DEPS//stage/unixodbc/include -I/MISSING/DEPS//stage/include -I/MISSING/DEPS//stage/unixodbc/include -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.9.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/Users/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/data_index-development/venv/include -I/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql/server -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/69.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
  In file included from psycopg/adapter_asis.c:28:
  ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:10: error: 'Python.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
  #include <Python.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~
           "Python.h"
  ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<python.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
  #include <Python.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~
           <python.h>
  In file included from psycopg/adapter_asis.c:28:
  In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:
  psycopg/Python.h:31:2: error: "psycopg requires Python 3.6"
  #error "psycopg requires Python 3.6"
   ^
  psycopg/Python.h:34:10: fatal error: 'structmember.h' file not found
  #include <structmember.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 warning and 3 errors generated.
  
  It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
  
  You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
  If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
  required for the build and try again.
  
  For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
  <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
  
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: '/Users/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/data_index-development/venv/bin/python' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fj/blrljwxs22q3csr4fqw7ycmc0000gn/T/pip-install-myo1zngt/psycopg2_e9a9698f63464cb99bc5bf3655675aa2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fj/blrljwxs22q3csr4fqw7ycmc0000gn/T/pip-install-myo1zngt/psycopg2_e9a9698f63464cb99bc5bf3655675aa2/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/fj/blrljwxs22q3csr4fqw7ycmc0000gn/T/pip-record-fkjtibr5/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers '/Users/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/data_index-development/venv/include/site/python3.9/psycopg2'
         cwd: /private/var/folders/fj/blrljwxs22q3csr4fqw7ycmc0000gn/T/pip-install-myo1zngt/psycopg2_e9a9698f63464cb99bc5bf3655675aa2/
    Complete output (55 lines):
    running install
    /Users/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/data_index-development/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
    
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg
    /usr/bin/clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/MISSING/DEPS//stage/include -I/MISSING/DEPS//stage/unixodbc/include -I/MISSING/DEPS//stage/include -I/MISSING/DEPS//stage/unixodbc/include -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.9.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/Users/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/data_index-development/venv/include -I/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql/server -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/69.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13.0-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
    In file included from psycopg/adapter_asis.c:28:
    ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:10: error: 'Python.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
    #include <Python.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~
             "Python.h"
    ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<python.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
    #include <Python.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~
             <python.h>
    In file included from psycopg/adapter_asis.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:
    psycopg/Python.h:31:2: error: "psycopg requires Python 3.6"
    #error "psycopg requires Python 3.6"
     ^
    psycopg/Python.h:34:10: fatal error: 'structmember.h' file not found
    #include <structmember.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning and 3 errors generated.
    
    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
    
    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
    
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: '/Users//Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/data_index-development/venv/bin/python' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fj/blrljwxs22q3csr4fqw7ycmc0000gn/T/pip-install-myo1zngt/psycopg2_e9a9698f63464cb99bc5bf3655675aa2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fj/blrljwxs22q3csr4fqw7ycmc0000gn/T/pip-install-myo1zngt/psycopg2_e9a9698f63464cb99bc5bf3655675aa2/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/fj/blrljwxs22q3csr4fqw7ycmc0000gn/T/pip-record-fkjtibr5/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers '/Users/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/data_index-development/venv/include/site/python3.9/psycopg2' Check the logs for full command output.
```

What can fix it?

Comment: Your screenshot shows that you installed `psycopg2` for the system interpreter, but did you install it for the interpreter being used by PyCharm? Usually PyCharm creates a virtual environment for each project with its own isolated interpreter.

Comment: 1º [Create a venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). 2º Then **activate the venv** on the command line before you run pip. 3º Choose the venv as interpreter in the IDE.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: @Brian Hi! updated the post with the error i get when trying to install in the virtual env and when install via the pycharm warning. Let me know what do you think

Comment: @bad_coder Thanks, updated that post with the error i got..

Comment: @Micha have you found out any solution for this?

Comment: @SarthakMittal have you checked if you installed the module for the correct interpreter?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur yes

Comment: @SarthakMittal open terminal, run `pip show psycopg2` to check whether it's really installed, then run `pip -V`. Now open Pycharm, open Terminal (Option + F12 by default), run `pip -V`, verify the output matches. Don't forget to drop the output here for further analysis.

Comment: @hoefling pip3 show psycopg2 -> WARNING: Package(s) not found: psycopg2 \b
pip -V -> pip 22.2.2 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)                                        
pip -V in pycharm terminal -> pip 21.3.1 from /Users/sarthakmittal/Documents/Sarthak/mbs/MBS_backedn_uat/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Usually had something similar happen to me while using anaconda, and I had to manually delete the folder location and reinstall to be importable (even with new enviroment).

I would suggest you try anaconda, miniconda with the same requirements and see if those help you out with your environment problem. Note: This requires [separate installation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/). Follow some of the [creation guides](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) but in general the essence would be something like:

`conda create --name testenv python=3.8`

`conda activate testenv`

`conda install psycopg2"==2.9.1" -c conda-forge`

After doing the last command in terminal, you are going to get something like this (just different version, but added into the command for 2.9.1):
[image]

You generally can search on [anaconda website](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/psycopg2) if you aren't familiar with the channels and the commands.

To check if everything is alright in the environment itself:

[image: Running psycopg2 in python terminal]

Now try to use this environment in PyCharm (by [changing the base interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#existing-environment) to the testenv one), if you still have problems do include the error message.

This also separates the issue from PyCharm or Pip wheel, and see if you can run get a running environment.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to build the psycopg package from source. That requires development files for Python, such as `Python.h`, which usually don't come automatically on macOS.

Instead, try the suggestion in the error message: install psycopg_binary:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

The installed package will just be psycopg2, but there is no need to compile it from source.